# Gradient of a homogeneous function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we have a continuous differentiable everywhere homogeneous function mapping $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ of degree 1 , i.e. $f(λx)=λf(x)$, then it's pretty easy to shοw that $f(x)=\nabla f(x)\bullet x$ by taking $\partial \over {\partial λ}$$f(λx)=$$\partial \over {\partial λ}$$λf(x)$ and setting $λ=1$.

But I'm curious what happens if $f(x)$ is differentiable only at $x=0$ and we define $f(0)=0$? I assume we'd get $f(x)=\nabla f(0)\bullet x$ but I can't quite see how to prove it rigorously without assuming it's differentiable at any point besides $x=0$. Hints/pointers on something obvious I'm missing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is called differentiable at $0\in \mathbb R^n$ if there is a linear operator $\nabla f(0) : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ so that

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(0 +h) - f(0) - \nabla f(0)\cdot h|}{|h|} = 0, $$

in this case we have

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(h) - \nabla f(0)\cdot h|}{|h|} = 0, $$

Now fix any $x\neq 0$. Put $h = \lambda x$. Then

$$\lim_{\lambda \to 0}\frac{|f(\lambda x) - \lambda\nabla f(0)\cdot x|}{|\lambda| |x|} = 0, $$

But $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$, so we have

$$\lim_{\lambda \to 0}\frac{|f( x) - \nabla f(0)\cdot x|}{ |x|} = 0, $$

which implies (as the term is independent of $\lambda$)

$$f( x) - \nabla f(0)\cdot x = 0.$$